# Change youtube/dailymotion/vimeo embed size

Tags: python, regex, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm writing python script where input is video url eg. http://www.youtube.com/embed/YX6eoRTaoUc

and it returns some info about video (duration, embed code and other like this...)

The problem is embed size returned by youtube and other video services (vimeo, dailymotion) are bad for me.

Eg.

```
<iframe width="480" width="260" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YX6eoRTaoUc?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need other values than 480 and 270. My approach was

```
    player_html = player_html.replace('width="480"','width="656"')
    player_html = player_html.replace('height="270"','height="517"')
```

But if youtube or other video service will send other value than 480 it will not work. Trying regex, but it was very hard to me.

This regex matches the width parameter, but what next?

```
    \W|^width="\d+"\W|$
```

Comment: Consider using a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper HTML parser will help you with this. Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> html = '''<iframe width="480" width="260" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YX6eoRTaoUc?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'''

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.iframe['width'] = 656
>>> soup.iframe['height'] = 517

>>> print print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="517" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YX6eoRTaoUc?feature=oembed" width="656">
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>

>>> html = unicode(soup)      # or str(soup) as required.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is using a responsive div, with no width, height specified

HTML:

```
<div class="responsive-video">
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nYM3dqntqfQ?theme=light&amp;autoplay=1&amp;vq=hd720&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.responsive-video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 60px; overflow: hidden;
}
```